# Caption positions in centered tables

Tags: tables, positioning

I wish to centre a table and that the caption will begin where the table begins (see the red line in the attached screenshot).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[H]\centering
\caption{Q\&A} \label{tab:mzdcq19}
\begin{tabular*}{.8\linewidth}{ll}
Question&Answer\\\hline
1+1
&2\\
1+2
&3\\
\end{tabular*}
\end{table} 
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the desired separation between the columns, you need to insert an `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` directive between the two columns.

Conversely, if you do *not* need the table to occupy a width of `0.8\textwidth` and are ok with it using natural column widths, you shouldn't use a `tabular*` environment> Use a `tabular` environment instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{OP's original form}
\begin{tabular*}{.8\linewidth}{ll}
Question&Answer\\\hline
1+1
&2\\
1+2
&3\\
\end{tabular*}

\vspace{5mm}
\caption{With \texttt{@\{\string\extracolsep\{\string\fill\}\}}}
\begin{tabular*}{.8\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l}
Question&Answer\\
\hline
1+1
&2\\
1+2
&3\\
\end{tabular*}

\vspace{5mm}
\caption{With \texttt{tabular} instead of \texttt{tabular*}}

\smallskip
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Question&Answer\\
\hline
1+1
&2\\
1+2
&3\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum to address the OP's follow-up comment*

It turns out that my initial answer failed to address the OP's objective. (This failure may have arisen because I was thrown off by what I perceived to be an unusual and unexplained absence of an `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` directive in a `tabular*` setting...)

While it's *possible* to employ a `threeparttable` environment to achieve the OP's objective, I think that doing so verges on overkill, as the *main capabilities* of that package -- `\tnote` macros and the `tablenotes` environment -- never get employed. As an alternative, and as a way to avoid the eccentric use of `tabular*`, I suggest (a) employing a `tabularx` environment, (b) embedding the caption and the `tabularx` environment in a `minipage` of width `0.8\linewidth`, and (c) using the capabilities of the `caption` package to left-align the caption within the `minipage`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text
\usepackage{tabularx,caption}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[ht!]
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false,skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}
\caption{Q\&A} \label{tab:mzdcq19}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lX} % use 'X' for the 2nd column
   Question&Answer\\ \hline
   1+1 &2 \\
   1+2 &3 \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}
\end{table} 
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your answer does not solve the caption issue I raised.

Comment: @MorZahavi - I guess it's because I got confused by your eccentric use of a `tabular*` environment to create a table of width `0.8\textwidth`. I'll post an addendum that shows how I would approach the entire setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `caption` and `threeparttable`: using the key `singlelinecheck=false` produces a caption starting at the beginning of the current line, like a normal paragraph; `threeparttable` measures the table width, so the current line  corresponds to this width. In addition, with the key `margin=\tabcolsep`, the caption begins where the table contents begins, if you prefer:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{float, caption, threeparttable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false, skip = 4pt}
\caption{Q\&A} \label{tab:mzdcq19}
\begin{tabular*}{.8\linewidth}{ll}
Question&Answer\\\hline
1+1
&2\\
1+2
&3\\
\end{tabular*}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false, skip=4pt, margin=\tabcolsep}
\caption{Q\&A} \label{tab:mzdcq19}
\begin{tabular*}{.8\linewidth}{ll}
Question&Answer\\\hline
1+1
&2\\
1+2
&3\\
\end{tabular*}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]